# Matplotlib Mollweide/Hammer projection: region of interest only

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections

I was wondering if there's a way to only show the region of interest from a plot based on Mollweide/Hammer projection in basemap (matplotlib).

I am trying to set the plot-bounds roughly to the Pacific plate, as in the link below. However, the set_xlim and set_ylim functions do not seem to have any effect. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

http://geology.gsapubs.org/content/29/8/695/F1.large.jpg

Comment: `Hammer` and `Mollweide` projections don't allow this since they print out entire world maps. A `Polyconic` projection can do this though but the boundaries are straight lines (the projection is applied but it uses a rectangle for the image boundaries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, both `Hammer` and `Mollweide` projections don't allow this as they print out entire world maps. Here's some code using `Polyconic` projection, but it is bounded by straight lines. The trick here is to define the corner longitude and latitudes on creation.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

my_map = Basemap(projection='poly', lat_0=0, lon_0=-160,
    resolution = 'h', area_thresh = 0.1,
    llcrnrlon=140, llcrnrlat=-60,
    urcrnrlon=-100, urcrnrlat=60)

plt.figure(figsize=(16,12))

my_map.drawcoastlines()
my_map.drawcountries()
my_map.fillcontinents(color='coral', lake_color='aqua')
my_map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')

my_map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 20))
my_map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 10))

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this effectively shows less area than the one in the picture you provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to put together this example. I'm just waiting to see if anyone else may have some input, before I accept this as the answer.