# Only upper half of Mollweide-Projection using Matplotlib Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections

I am currently trying to create a pcolormesh-plot of data that is given defined on only the upper half of a sphere, so the azimuthal angle spans the full 2 pi, but the polar angle is `0 < theta < pi/2`.

The desired result would be a plot using the Mollweide projection but not displaying the lower half. Without Basemap, I tried changing the axe limits with `ax.set_ylim(lims)`, which produced an error that told me that this function is disabled when using projections and suggested using Basemap instead.

I have made several attempts to change the limits using e.g. `llcrnrlon` etc., but this seems to make sense only for plots limited by a rectangular box. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176169/matplotlib-mollweide-hammer-projection-region-of-interest-only) suggests using a Polyconic projection, but I could not achieve producing my desired output.

If anyone has an idea how this could be done, let me know. Thanks!

EDIT:
This is a code example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lims_phi = [-np.pi., np.pi]
lims_the = [0., np.pi/2.]

phi = np.linspace(lims_phi[0], lims_phi[1], 10)
the = np.linspace(lims_the[0], lims_the[1], 10)

THE, PHI = np.meshgrid(np.rad2deg(the), np.rad2deg(phi))

Z = np.cos(np.deg2rad(THE))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

lat_bounds = 0., np.rad2deg(np.pi/2)
long_bounds = 0., np.rad2deg(np.pi)
m = Basemap(projection='moll', lon_0=0, ax=ax)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,90.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,60.))

im = m.pcolormesh(PHI, THE, Z, cmap='Reds', latlon=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Share your code, please

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. The data is pretty random in the example. I just want to not draw the bottom half of the projection.